# CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

Tags: c#, sum, addition

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a = Convert.ToInt32(ltAvailable.Text);
    int b = Convert.ToInt32(txtInput.Text);
    ltTotal.Text = a + b;
```

How can i add values in a literal and a textbox? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here:

```
ltTotal.Text = (a + b).ToString();
```

Comment: how can i update my table value from lttotal.Text? thanks man.

Comment: @JGarma, That's a separate question and it's not obvious what to tell you from the example code given.

Comment: So i have a column "Available" on my Products table. I designed a form that has a textbox that will add its value and the current value from the "Available" column. How can i generate the code? So far, this is my code. Sorry, noob here.

Comment: int a = Convert.ToInt32(ltAvailable.Text);
        int b = Convert.ToInt32(txtInput.Text);
        ltTotal.Text = (a + b).ToString();

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Products SET Available=@Available WHERE ProductID=@ProductID";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Available", ltAvailable.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Response.Redirect("Details.aspx");

Comment: how can i convert my comment to a code one haha sorry

Comment: @JGarma you can use the back-tick \` or graph character. The one below the tilde ~ on your keyboard. (Assuming QWERTY keyboard)

Comment: @JGarma, that's beyond the scope of this question. Please do some research. There are examples out there of adding a "table" to a WinForm and updating the columns, etc. Try that and then comeback and ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a = Convert.ToInt32(ltAvailable.Text);
    int b = Convert.ToInt32(txtInput.Text);
    ltTotal.Text = (a + b).ToString();
```

You just need to call `.ToString()` on your calculation result

This would also work

```
ltTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(a + b)
```

Comment: ow can i update my table value from lttotal.Text? thanks man

Comment: what table value? you don't mention any table in your question. probably better for a separate question